# How to disable GraphQL mutation/query name suggestions?

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-server

I've disabled introspection with the npm module 'graphql-disable-introspection', but e.g. `https://HOSTNAME/graphql?query={user_}`
results in GraphQL API suggesting mutations and queries which have a similar name to
”user_”.
I want to avoid automatically showing our mutations and queries to anyone, how it is possible to disable these suggestions?

Comment: Why are you trying to protect queries and mutations? You should i guess protect data using roles and privileges.

Comment: I do protect using roles and privileges, but I don't want to autosuggest or list possible mutations/queries either.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: at the moment it's not possible. The `graphql` npm module does not offer such an option. I may submit a PR in the future with a `disableSuggestions: boolean` argument.

Update: However, it is possible in another way, via the `formatError` graphql handler.

```js
 if (error.message?.indexOf("Did you mean")) error.message = "Invalid query";
```

Comment: I don't know why you'd get a -1 on this, it's just true that it's not really possible atm. Thanks for suggesting the `formatError` fn!

Comment: Reference to the GQL issue tracking this feature: https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/issues/2247